# how to create a multiple labels dynamically in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to create a multiple labels with text dynamically like this
[image]

Sample code is as following:

```
name=[vj,aj,bon...]
percentage=[96,85,90,65....]
domain=[html,js,css,java...]
```

and view buttons.I don't have any idea to do like this.

Comment: Where do you want to display 'name' and the apperance should be exactly same?

Comment: name should be in top of domain
apperance should be same@Aybars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom widget to wrap the four objects (3 labels and 1 button) inside a `frame` and then create custom widgets based on your arrays.  Below is a sample code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class MyLabel(Frame):
  def __init__(self, master, name, percentage, domain):
    Frame.__init__(self, master, bd=2, relief='raised')
    Label(self, text='%3d%%'%percentage, font=('Arial', 24), fg='#88F', width=4, anchor='e').grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)
    Label(self, text=name, font=('Aria', 16, 'bold'), fg='black', width=15, anchor='w').grid(row=0, column=1)
    Label(self, text=', '.join(domain), font=('Aria', 10), fg='black').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
    Button(self, text='View', fg='white', bg='#44F').grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=2, padx=10)
    self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

name = ['vj', 'aj', 'bon', 'hi']
percentage = [96, 85, 90, 65]
domain = [['html','css','js'], ['java','kotlin','python'], ['html','python'], ['java','html','css','js']]

for i, n in enumerate(name):
  MyLabel(root, n, percentage[i], domain[i]).pack(expand=True, fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

and the output:

[image]

Comment: is there any options to delete these labels and recreate with new values,i am trying to do but it is not coming@acw1668

Comment: You can add a `delete` button to `MyLabel` and set the `command` option of the `delete` button to `lambda: self.pack_forget()`.

Comment: i want it to dynamically remove when new data is available.i tried your method but thats not my requirement
i will clearly explain the scenario:i have tied the mylabel class to a function my data will come dynamically.when i run the function the label is inserted in frame,when i run the same function its just append below the same frame its not deleting the old labels.i want a function that should delete the old labels in the frame and insert the label with new frames@acw1668

Comment: If you have save the instances of `MyLabel`, you can use `instance.pack_forget()` to delete the `MyLabel` instance.